# VPC VPN SSH stalls at host verification

Tags: ssh, vpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, meraki

I have set up a VPN tunnel to our VPC on Amazon which consists of a public subnet with a couple machines, one NAT instance, and then several private subnets with an assortment of machines as well. I can see the machines in the VPC from our local network, Ive added ICMP and SSH from our local network IP range to the VPC security group and can ping/nmap the private IPs of the servers just fine (seeing port 22 is open.)

I can SSH into the public subnet instances that have public IPs with no problem. The issue I'm having is SSH'ing into any of the machines from the private/public subnet private IPs.

SSH spits out:

```
   ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/redacted.pem ec2-user@11.0.0.139
   OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: Connecting to 11.0.0.139 [11.0.0.139] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/redacted.pem type -1
   debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/redacted.pem-cert type -1
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6p1-hpn14v5
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
   debug1: Remote is NON-HPN aware
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x14000000
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
   debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
   debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
   debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

At which point it sits for a while, finally returning:

```
   Connection closed by 11.0.0.139
```

The VPN is set up with static routing, and the tunnel is up. Route tables are propegating our local 192.18.0.0/16 network IP range through the Virtual Private Gateway. Networking ACLs are completely open IN and OUT.

Yet I'm not sure why I dont get a host verification step back from the server?

`tcpdump` shows this:

```
   > sudo tcpdump -vvv 'tcp port 22 and host 11.0.0.139'
   tcpdump: listening on enp0s20u1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
   12:36:26.096254 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56385, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0xb16e (correct), seq 989731254, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3130871 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   12:36:26.141295 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
       11.0.0.139.ssh > HOSTNAME.55391: Flags [S.], cksum 0x3b34 (correct), seq 3868019661, ack 989731255, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 1060770 ecr 3130871,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   12:36:26.141372 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56386, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xef39 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 3130885 ecr 1060770], length 0
   12:36:26.141828 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56387, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 83)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb8b4 (correct), seq 1:32, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 3130885 ecr 1060770], length 31
   12:36:26.185005 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 25699, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
       11.0.0.139.ssh > HOSTNAME.55391: Flags [.], cksum 0xef22 (correct), seq 1, ack 32, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 1060781 ecr 3130885], length 0
   12:36:26.188702 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 25700, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 73)
       11.0.0.139.ssh > HOSTNAME.55391: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2e5c (correct), seq 1:22, ack 32, win 210, options [nop,nop,TS val 1060782 ecr 3130885], length 21
   12:36:26.188813 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56388, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xeeeb (correct), seq 32, ack 22, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 3130899 ecr 1060782], length 0
   12:36:26.483445 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56395, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xdabd (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3130988 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:26.976751 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56396, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xda29 (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3131136 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:27.966780 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56397, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xd900 (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3131433 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:29.943400 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56398, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xd6af (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3132026 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:33.896741 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56399, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xd20d (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3133212 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:41.803450 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56400, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xc8c9 (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3135584 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:36:57.643373 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56401, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0xb639 (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3140336 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:37:29.270027 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56402, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1438)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x9129 (correct), seq 32:1418, ack 1566, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3149824 ecr 1060793], length 1386
   12:38:26.189231 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 25707, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
       11.0.0.139.ssh > HOSTNAME.55391: Flags [F.], cksum 0x86da (correct), seq 1566, ack 32, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1090782 ecr 3130899,nop,nop,sack 1 {1418:2000}], length 0
   12:38:26.190197 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56403, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 132)
       HOSTNAME.55391 > 11.0.0.139.ssh: Flags [FP.], cksum 0x437d (correct), seq 2000:2080, ack 1567, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 3166900 ecr 1090782], length 80
   12:38:26.232692 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 41287, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
       11.0.0.139.ssh > HOSTNAME.55391: Flags [R], cksum 0x6dc0 (correct), seq 3868021228, win 0, length 0
```

What would be the cause to prevent SSH finishing the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that MTU size is 1436 on your interface, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: Unfortunately, seems as though even with my interface set to 1436 MTU, it still has the same issue.

Comment: Looks like you were correct, the problem was my lack of understanding in how MTU worked along each hop. Setting my laptop interface to 1436 would have been correct if it did not pass through anything that had adjusts the IP packet (vlan, switches, sec appliances) that or one of those had a smaller MTU forcing the fragmentation. I ended up having to set my MTU to 1422.

Comment: Wireshark was immensely helpful in figuring out the actual value you would have to set it to